# IIS 10 Failed Request 500 - General_Request_Start Failed To Complete

Tags: azure-cloud-services, internal-server-error, iis-10, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to understand why after deployment my server is returning 500 - Internal server error for a simple GET request that checks the server's status which is supposed to return 200 (when I run it locally with unit tests I wrote, it works fine). I retrieved the failed request log, but can't quite seem to understand what the problem is.
In several events the severity column shows: **Failed To Complete**

The Request summary shows:
[image]

These are the Errors and Warnings shown:
[image: The Errors and Warnings shown]

Does anyone know why I might be getting theses errors, or why I might be getting a 500 Internal Server error response?

I will add that I already have a GET request that is working:

https://myalertsserver.cloudapp.net/providers/management/alerts which returns 200.

and when I try:

https://myalertsserver.cloudapp.net/providers/status I get a 404 Error.

It seems to me like it has to do with something in the configuration, but I can't seem to understand what.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd better ignore all those shining things and open the raw log file in an editor to locate the actual information about the 500 error.

Comment: What did you see in event viewer application log or http.sys httperr log?